# How can you get an image to update as a databinded value changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, binding

I have a class `cTailoredReading` and a string property for an image. Right now, the below code works. When I create an instance of the class and set the `datacontext`, the image control updates and shows the specified image.

However, when I call `DisplayedImageChange` it isn't updating the image control.

Any advice / pointers would be really helpful as I've been struggling on this for a few days.

**cTailoredReading.cs**:

```
class cTailoredReading
    {
        public cTailoredReading(string sTitle, string sFocus)
        {
            Title = sTitle;
            Focus = sFocus;

            Title_Image = @"C:\Users\local-paul\Pictures\Elly\3rd Birthday Photoshoot\BABY0363.JPG";
        }

        public void DisplayedImageChange()
        {
            Title_Image =  @"C:\Users\local-paul\Pictures\Elly\3rd Birthday Photoshoot\BABY0364.JPG"; 
        }

        public string Title_Image { get; set; }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="ResourceMainImage" Source="{Binding Title_Image}" Width="80" Height="80"/>
```

### RESOLVED

Thanks CFun, I resolved the issue with the following changes:

**cTailoredReading.cs**:

```
class cTailoredReading : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public cTailoredReading(string sTitle, string sFocus)
        {
            Title = sTitle;
            Focus = sFocus;

            Title_Image = @"C:\Users\local-paul\Pictures\Elly\3rd Birthday Photoshoot\BABY0363.JPG";
        }

        public void DisplayedImageChange()
        {
            Title_Image =  @"C:\Users\local-paul\Pictures\Elly\3rd Birthday Photoshoot\BABY0364.JPG"; 
        }

        //public string Title_Image { get; set; }

private string _Title_Image;
public string Title_Image {
            get
            {
                return _Title_Image;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.Title_Image)
                {
                    _Title_Image = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to implement [inotifypropertychanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) lot of examples are available around just search for [`inotifypropertychanged`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inotifypropertychanged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not implementing it as it should, try with the following:

```
private string _Title_Image;
public string Title_Image {
    get
    {
        return _Title_Image;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.Title_Image)
        {
            _Title_Image = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I realised, so I was just updating my post as you replied here. Thanks again.